# Dagger 2 Implementation With Dynamic Objects

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

So I am trying to get my head around Dagger2 and it's dependency injection. Here is my current setup.

**SQLiteModelModule**

```
@Module
public class SQLiteModelModule {

    private final int versionNumber;
    private final Context context;
    private final String databaseName;

    public SQLiteModelModule( Context context, String databaseName, int versionNumber ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SQLite providesSQLite() {
        return SQLite.newInstance(context,databaseName,versionNumber);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SQLiteModel providesSQLiteModel( SQLite sqlite) {
        return new SQLiteModel( sqlite );
    }

}
```

Because this is a library and the `ModelManager` may contain different modules other than the `SQLiteModel` I have created a `TestModelManagerModule` to provide the manager.

**TestModelManagerModule**

```
@Module
public class TestModelManagerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ModelManager providesModelManager( SQLiteModel model ) {
        ModelManager manager = new ModelManager();
        manager.registerModel(model,"sosmv1",true);
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Then to tie them all together for my tests I have a test component.

**SQLiteTestComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component( modules = {TestModelManagerModule.class, SQLiteModelModule.class})
public interface SQLiteTestComponent {
    ModelManager provideModelManager();
}
```

This works when I do the following and the correct type of 'IModel' Object is returned.

```
private ModelManager modelManager;
private SQLiteTestComponent sqLiteTestComponent;
@Before
public void setup() {
    Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    this.sqLiteTestComponent = DaggerSQLiteTestComponent.builder()
                                                    .sQLiteModelModule(new SQLiteModelModule(context, "TestDB", 1))
                                                    .build();

    this.modelManager = sqLiteTestComponent.provideModelManager();
}

@Test
public void testCreation() {
    IModel model = modelManager.getDefaultModel();
    Assert.assertEquals(SQLiteModel.class, model.getClass());
}
```

**MY QUESTION**

I have a class `OMKObject` that has a dependency on `ModelManager`. It uses this dependency not only in constructors but also in a field. How do I go about injecting this?

Also is the above all correct? Or have I done something wrong in the setup?